# Graphics en Java con botón

Tags: java

Hola tengo este programa, que hace rectángulos de colores, al darle al botón de colorear pinta el rectángulo con el valor de cada slider. Mi problema es que cuanto hago clic al botón de colorear pinta el rectángulo y también el botón...si alguien me puede ayudar, aquí dejo el código.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class PantallaPintar implements ActionListener {
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;
private JButton bRojo, bVerde, bAzul, bColorea;
private JSlider sRojo, sVerde, sAzul;
private Pintar v;
public static void main(String [] args) {
    PantallaPintar f = new PantallaPintar();
}

public PantallaPintar() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("Vamos a pintar!");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(100,100,800,400);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(0, 0,800, 400);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    bRojo = new JButton("Rojo");
    bRojo.setBounds(10,36,89,23);
    bRojo.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(bRojo);

    bVerde = new JButton("Verde");
    bVerde.setBounds(10,105,89,23);
    bVerde.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(bVerde);

    bAzul = new JButton("Azul");
    bAzul.setBounds(10,174,89,23);
    bAzul.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(bAzul);

    sRojo = new JSlider(0,255,0);
    sRojo.setBounds(142,36,200,26);
    panel.add(sRojo);

    sVerde = new JSlider(0,255,0);
    sVerde.setBounds(142,102,200,26);
    panel.add(sVerde);

    sAzul = new JSlider(0,255,0);
    sAzul.setBounds(142,174,200,26);
    panel.add(sAzul);

    bColorea = new JButton("Colorea");
    bColorea.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(bColorea);
    bColorea.setBounds(120,230,89,23);

    v = new Pintar();
    panel.add(v);
    v.setBounds(400, 25, 350, 180);
    v.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

 }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == bColorea) {
        v.setRed(sRojo.getValue());
        v.setGreen(sVerde.getValue());
        v.setBlue(sAzul.getValue());
        v.repaint();
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == bRojo) {

    }
}
```

}

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Pintar extends JPanel {
private int red;
private int green;
private int blue;

public Pintar() {
    setRed(0);
    setGreen(0);
    setBlue(0);
}
public Pintar(int red_aux, int green_aux, int blue_aux) {
    setRed(red_aux);
    setGreen(green_aux);
    setBlue(blue_aux);
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Color c = new Color(getRed(), getGreen(), getBlue());
    g.setColor(c);
    g.fillRect(10,10,this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
}
public void setRed(int red_aux) {
    red = red_aux;
}
public int getRed() {
    return red;
}
public void setGreen(int green_aux) {
    green = green_aux;
}
public int getGreen() {
    return green;
}
public void setBlue(int blue_aux) {
    blue = blue_aux;
}
public int getBlue() {
    return blue;
}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta con el código en texto y no en imagen para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Parece un problema del `setLayout(null)`. Al dejarlo en null puede ocasionar estos problemas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

Saludos, Daniel.

Lo que pasa no es problema del `Layout` que utilizas, sin embargo, siempre es una buena práctica usar `layouts` y no asignarlo a `null`.

El verdadero problema es que en el método `paintComponent` de tu clase `Pintar` has eliminado `super.paintComponent(g);` lo cuál realiza una llamada a la implementación de la clase padre de ese método, es decir, de la clase `JPanel` de la cual se extiende tu clase `Pintar`, asegúrate de que tu método se vea así:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Color c = new Color(getRed(), getGreen(), getBlue());
    g.setColor(c);
    g.fillRect(10,10,this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
}
```

He aquí el resultado, como ves ya no se pintan los componentes:

[image: gif]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias.